# In case of unupvotes, do you lose the reputation that you didn't get due to the rep cap?

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

Let's say a user has 500 initial reputation and they post a question that goes to HNQ. The question gains 100 upvotes in 2 days and then the upvoting stops. So the user now has 900 reputation due to the rep cap.

I was wondering for example what would happen if two months later theoretically 90 users unupvote the question? Will the user go to 1 reputation even though he had 500 initial reputation, or will it stop at 500?

To put it better, *in case of unupvotes, do you lose the reputation that you didn't get due to the rep cap*?

I know the question is not really that practical, and I'm not going into why that many users would do it, but the situation if it happened, what would happen to the rep.

Comment: A related point: if the system calculated each upvote, then stopped at the rep cap, an extra 40 votes were made, then all the first ones were undone, would the extra 40 be calculated? (I don't doubt they would, but still...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unupvoting merely results in your rep being calculated as if the original upvote was never cast in the first place.  It doesn't just remove 5/10 reputation unconditionally.

So the user would end up with 550 reputation at the end, as from the system's perspective it would be as if the question was only ever upvoted 10 times, and the other 90 upvotes were never cast.

Comment: Is there an "official" source for this information?